# Can you signal a condition variable from a different mutex from the one that is waiting?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

For example, in pseudocode:

```
lock mutex1
pthread_cond_wait(condition, mutex1)
unlock mutex1
```

...from another thread:

```
lock mutex2
pthread_cond_signal(condition)
unlock mutex2
```

Does the calling thread have to have a lock on the same mutex that is waiting? It seems to me that this would limit the use of condition variables, when you have many threads running at the same time that would like to communicate with each other.

Comment: How exactly do you think this would limit it? Is it because of additional time to lock/unlock the mutex? Cv implementation on Linux will usually have an internal mutex exactly because it _has_ to support signalling outside of the usually critical section.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I'm a complete beginner on multithreading so I really have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutex2` is irrelevant to your example, you may as well not hold any mutex in the notifier.

The docs say:

> pthread_cond_signal() may be called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that threads calling pthread_cond_wait() have associated with the condition variable during their waits; however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal().

It doesn't sound like you require any specific wakeup scheduling behavior, so yes you can signal the condition variable without holding any mutex at all, or when holding unrelated mutexes.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly is "predictable scheduling behavior"?  I'm not sure whether i need that or not.

Comment: For example if you hold the waiter's mutex you can prevent it from continuing to execute until you release that mutex and perhaps wait on something else yourself.  Most applications don't need predictable scheduling.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SamuelNoyes: Note that (without any "predictable scheduling behavior" at all) here's no guarantee that one thread won't send the signal before the other thread starts waiting for the signal; causing the other thread to wait for a signal it was too late to see. Solutions to this problem typically involve using some kind of variable or data structure to tell the waiter if it should wait or not, which leads to both threads using the same mutex to avoid race conditions (to guard against "checking if it should wait, then the signal arriving, then starting to wait for the signal").

Comment: @Brendan You *always* need a shared predicate for condition variables (unlike semaphores), because condition variables may have spurious wakeups. The woken-up thread must check the condition and wait again if the condition is not appropriate to continue. The signaling thread typically has to hold the mutex to modify some state checked by the predicate anyway (unless the state is atomic), because otherwise the unsynchronized access would be UB. However, the signaling thread **does not have to be holding the mutex when signalling**, it can signal after releasing the mutex without UB or race.